# Запуск SPA на Android

Tags: javascript, android, spa

Добрый день! Имеется одностраничное приложение js, css, html, мы его запускаем на винде в хроме с флагами – получается терминал-киоск.
Стоит задача запустить его на Android планшете, в связи с этим вопросы:

- Можно ли запускать Chrome на Android с флагами?
- Как скрыть весь интерфейс андроида?
- Как обеспечить автозапуск страницы-приложения?

Писать приложения на Android не охота, желательно использовать стандартные средства или готовые утилиты.

Answer (score 1):

Хром с флагами запустить не выйдет, это просто невозможно с точки зрения ОС.

Нормального киоск мода в андроиде нет. Более того, все доступные решения проблемы требуют написания Android-приложения, просто запустить SPA в стороннем браузере не выйдет. Впрочем, сделать приложение с одним `WebView`, которое показывает ваше SPA с диска или загружает страницу из интернета -- это наиболее простая часть.

Начиная с 6й версии есть такая вещь, как [lock task mode](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html#create-dpc), которая доступна только для Android for Work. Делает как раз то, что надо, включается несложно, но разобраться с Android for Work и развернуть инфраструктуру куда сложнее.

Начиная с 5й версии есть такая фича как "[App pinning](http://gadgetguideonline.com/android/lollipop/how-to-use-screen-pinning-in-android-lollipop/)", которая позволяет закрепить одно приложение на экране и заблокировать все остальные, включая нотификации и звонки. Другое дело, что выйти из этого режима можно просто нажав комбинацию клавиш, так что непонятно зачем это надо, просто имейте ввиду, что такая фича есть.

Если у Вас девайс от самсунг, то у них есть [своё решение](https://seap.samsung.com/sample-app/kiosk-mode) для киоск мода, но оно требует регистрации и получения лицензии.

Если нужна поддержка девайсов менее 5й версии, то всё плохо. Вкратце, нужно сделать Ваше приложение лаунчером и установить в качестве лаунчера по умолчанию, плюс применить максимальное количество затычек, убирающих всякие шорткаты в настройки и системный UI. Root-права, кстати, весьма упрощают задачу.

Описание проблемы и опыт решения в 2012м году есть [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/149561/), а вот [здесь](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/) другая более современная статья, которая по крайней мере обещает решить все проблемы, увы, не могу гарантировать, что там буквально всё заблокировано. Впрочем в статье рекламируется какое-то говое решение, может Вам поможет.